# Handle cls and self in method decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following problem for which I try to find the most Pythonic way possible. I have a solution, but it simply does not feel Pythonic enough. Maybe you know a more elegant solution?

**The Problem is**

In a decorator, I would like to

1. look up the names of the arguments of a function
2. extract the arguments from a JSON string
3. pass them to the function in the right order

The decorator should be generic for all function types, which are `staticmethod`, `classmethod`, `instance method`(with self), or `functional method`(outside of class). *I made the last 2 names up. Please comment if you know how you actually call such functions. Thank you.* This poses the problem that sometimes the arguments passed to the decorator contain a class object or a class instance and sometimes not.

Let's assume my project looks as follows:

```
import inspect

@the_decorator
def fun_method(name, password):
    pass

class ExampleClass:
    @staticmethod
    @the_decorator
    def static_method(name, password):
        pass

    @classmethod
    @the_decorator
    def class_method(cls, name, password):
        pass

    @the_decorator
    def instance_method(self, name, password):
        pass
```

**My solution so far**

```
def the_decorator(func):
    params = list(inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys())

    def get_func_args(data_json, keys):
        data_dict = json.loads(data_json)
        return [data_dict.get(p) for p in keys]

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        if inspect.isclass(args[0]) or params[0] == 'self':
            func_args = get_func_args(args[1], params[1:])
            func_args = [args[0]] + func_args
        else:
            func_args = get_func_args(args[0], params)

        if None in func_args:
            raise ValueError('Not all necessary data was passed.')

        return func(*func_args)

    return wrapper
```

Comment: 1) Why do you need to look up the names of the arguments? I think you should only care about their order. 2) Do you really want to mess with JSON and not simply use `**kwargs` (a.k.a. keyword arguments)?

Comment: 1) Since `json.loads()` returns a `dict`, which is not ordered, I cannot ensure that the arguments will be passed on to the function in the right order (name  could receive data of password and vice versa)
2) Yes, I would like to keep using arguments instead of `kwargs`. Its cleaner  and I think a well written decorator is better than using kwargs everywhere.

Comment: But then you'd have to pass JSON data as one of the function's parameters, as in `function('[123, "hello", 3.141, {"dictionary": "yay!"}]')`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I get your point, but these functions are tightly connected to an API which always receives and passes on JSON strings. I understand that this makes the functions less reusable, but if I want to use the functions as you described then I can always remove the decorator, extract the args from JSON where necessary, and call the function as usual with e.g. `function(123, "hello", ...)`

Comment: The API uses JSON because it (JSON) has been made for this: it enables you to transfer data between code that supports that format, no matter what language they were written it. JSON is used for _serialization_. Once you receive a serialized object, you normally _deserialize_ it (i.e. convert to your language's type(s)) and then continue working only with the deserialized version. Why deserialize every time you call a function? It can be rather inefficient and result in hard to understand code.